# Read array line by line 3 values by 3 values

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to read my array line by line 3 values by 3 values. So when I recover 3 values put in my matrix etc etc...

```
for(int i=0; i<_height; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<_width; j++) {
        result = ifile.get();
        (image)[i][j]= (int)result;
        // Display the array which contains data
        cout << (image)[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: And your question is actually?

Comment: If your file contains values in text format, you may want to use `ifile >> result;`.

Comment: How can I do this, retrieve line by line 3 values by 3 values?

Comment: what is "3 values by 3 values" ? Maybe it would help if you outline the format of the data in the file

Comment: first line 4 5 6 5 6 7 8 9 0 second line 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 8 0 and have 4 5 6 after 5 6 7 after 8 9 0 at the first line . The same way for the second line

Comment: You could search the internet for "c++ read file matrix".

Comment: The notation `(image)[i][j]` is not exactly wrong, but it is not the way you should be writing array access; you should use just `image[i][j]`.

Comment: Please edit your sample data and discussion about it into the question where you can format it (you can, and should, edit your own question).  What do you want to happen if the first line contains 4 values instead of 3?  If it contains 2 values instead of 3?  Or, given the comments about 9 values on the first line, what should happen if there are just 8 values, or 10 values?  It seems clear to me that you should be reading a line into a string and then parsing the string, rather than reading values one at a time because that doesn't care about line boundaries.

Comment: so each line in the file is a 3x3 matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < 3; ++row)
{
    for (unsigned int column = 0; column < 3; ++column)
    {
        inFile >> image[row][column];
    }
}
```

Since your values are separated by "white space", which is spaces, tabs or newlines, this should work regardless of whether all values are on one line or many.

**Edit 1: A safer alternative**
The above assumes there is always 9 values and they are all valid integers.
If something goes awry, the above won't work.  The following is a more robust method.

```
unsigned int row = 0;
unsigned int column = 0;
bool all_values_read = false;
int value = 0;
while ((inFile >> value) && !all_values_read)
{
  image[row][column] = value;
  ++column;
  if (column >= 3)
  {
      column = 0;
      ++row;
      if (row >= 3)
      {
         all_values_read = true;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something like follows:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<_height; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<_width; j = j +3) {
        result = ifile.get(i,j);
        (image)[i][count]= (int)result;
        count += 1;
        // Display the array which contains data
        cout << (image)[i][count] << " ";
    }
    count = 0;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Where the `get(int i, int j)` function is a function that recovers the three values (or less if the line ends before `j+3`) starting from the position `j` of the `i-th` row.

Comment: Of course, you need also to provide all the necessary checks. The attached code is just an idea!

Comment: no count++ please?

Comment: Feel free to edit ;)